# Replace substring with binary strings

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, binary, postgresql-9.2

I want to perform a substring replace operation on binary strings. There is a function available that does this exact thing for strings of type `text` ([c.f.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html)):

```
replace(string text, from text, to text)
```

But unfortunately none for binary strings of type `bytea` ([c.f.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-binarystring.html)).

Now I wonder, do I need to reimplement this operation for binary strings or can I use the corresponding basic string function for this task? Are there edge cases that could break my application:

```
select replace('\000\015Hello World\000\015Hello World'::bytea::text,
               'World',
               'Jenny')::bytea
```

I couldn't find a specific note in the documentation so far. Can someone help me on that?

Comment: What's your postgresql version? the links you provide mix 9.2 and 8.0 doc pages, and the interpretation of backslash in strings also depend on the version.

Comment: @DanielVérité it's version 9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the suggestion by @DanielVérité I have implemented a `plpgsql` function that does  a string replace with binary strings of type `bytea`.
In the implementation I only used functions from the binary strings section, so I think it should be safe to use.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
replace_binary(input_str bytea, pattern bytea, replacement bytea)
RETURNS bytea
AS $$
DECLARE
    buf bytea;
    pos integer;
BEGIN
    buf := '';
    -- validate input
    IF coalesce(length(input_str), 0) = 0 OR coalesce(length(pattern), 0) = 0
    THEN
        RETURN input_str;
    END IF;
    replacement := coalesce(replacement, '');
    LOOP
        -- find position of pattern in input
        pos := position(pattern in input_str);
        IF pos = 0 THEN
            -- not found: append remaining input to buffer and return
            buf := buf || substring(input_str from 1);
            RETURN buf;
        ELSE
            -- found: append substring before pattern to buffer
            buf := buf || substring(input_str from 1 for pos - 1);
            -- append replacement
            buf := buf || replacement;
            -- go on with substring of input
            input_str := substring(input_str from pos + length(pattern));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```

As for my test cases it works quite well:

```
with input(buf, pattern, replacement) as (values 
    ('tt'::bytea, 't'::bytea, 'ttt'::bytea),
    ('test'::bytea, 't'::bytea, 'ttt'::bytea),
    ('abcdefg'::bytea, 't'::bytea, 'ttt'::bytea),
    ('\000\015Hello 0orld\000\015Hello 0orld'::bytea, '0'::bytea, '1'::bytea))

select encode(replace_binary(buf, pattern, replacement), 'escape') from input;
```

outputs as expected:

```
               encode               
------------------------------------
 tttttt
 tttesttt
 abcdefg
 \000\rHello 1orld\000\rHello 1orld
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with casting to `text` and back to `bytea` is that it wouldn't work if the replacement strings involved quoted bytes in strings. Let's see with an example.

(I'm setting `bytea_output` to `hex` to better see the text, otherwise it's all hex numbers)

Initial query:

```
 with input(x) as (values (('\000\015Hello World\000\015Hello World'::bytea)))
  select replace(x::text, 'World', 'Jenny')::bytea from input;
```

The result is fine:

```
                replace                 
----------------------------------------
 \000\015Hello Jenny\000\015Hello Jenny
(1 row)
```

But if trying with a modified version that wants to replace the character `0` by `1`

```
with input(x) as (values (('\000\015Hello 0orld\000\015Hello 0orld'::bytea)))
  select replace(x::text, '0', '1')::bytea from input;
```

The result is:

```
                replace                 
----------------------------------------
 IMHello 1orldIMHello 1orld
```

whereas the desired result would be: `\000\015Hello 1orld\000\015Hello 1orld`.
This happens because the intermediate representation `\000\015` gets replaced by `\111\115`

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought the `::text`-representation would leave the non-printable bytes single bytes, but indeed, `octet_length(x)` is not equal `octet_length(x::text)`. Does there exist/Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: I don't see a simple workaround. I think I'd do it iteratively in `plpgsql` without casts to text and using `position` to locate and `overlay` to replace, in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table_name
set column_name = decode(
        replace(encode(column_name, 'escape'), 'old_text', 'new_text'),
        'escape'
    );
```

Comment: This won't work: the replacement can destroy the escape sequences.